# How to avoid repeating nouns, using an adjective?

Tags: grammar, noun, adjective

I wanted to write

> *Rather than famous writers, I like predominantly unknown ones.*

in German, and I was trying with

> Ich mag überwiegend/eher unbekannte Schriftsteller, mehr als bekannte Schriftsteller.

or

> Ich bevorzuge normalerweise unbekannte Schiftsteller bekannten Schiftstellern gegenüber.

but it's too repetitive. I don't know how to substitute the *bekannte Schriftsteller* for  only *bekannte*. Intuition tells me that it should be something like

> Ich mag überwiegend unbekannte Schriftsteller, mehr als *Bekannte/bekannte*.   (Klein oder Groß?)

or

> Ich bevorzuge normalerweise unbekannte Schiftsteller *Bekannten/bekannten* gegenüber.
>    (Klein oder Groß?)

**Edit**. As Emanuel pointed out (c.f. the comments bellow his answer), writing *Bekannte* in this last sentence would lead to a confusion, for it could be mixed with *acquaintances*. Discusing the adjective-dependence is then also encouraged. Try, say, with the simpler

> Ich mag eher blaue Dinge; mehr als *rote/Rote*. (Klein oder Groß?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Emanuel hat Deine konkreten Fragen beantwortet. Daher nur noch ein zusätzlicher Gedanke: Die Wiederholung im Deutschen, die Du in dem englischen Satz nicht hattest, kam eigentlich daher, dass Dir für “famous” kein anderes Wort als „bekannt“ eingefallen ist. Nun ist “famouș” vielleicht auch nicht gleich „berühmt“, aber es gibt ja zum Glück Wörterbücher. Wie wäre denn zum Beispiel folgendes?

> Ich ziehe namhaften Schriftstellern vorwiegend unbekannte vor.

Das ist auch näher an Deinem englischen Satz, weil ich nicht ganz klar ist, worauf sich „vorwiegend“ bezieht, und bei “predominantly” war ich mir auch nicht ganz sicher ;)

Comment: Wow super Idee!!...nur eine Kleinigkeit: bezieht sich das worwiegend auf das Verb oder auf unbekannte? Beides ist möglich. Vielleicht gibt es eine eindeutigere Lösung? (mir fällt keine ein)... in jedem Fall +1

Answer (score 1):

Your feeling that the first version is too repetitive is correct. Also, your solution is quite good but there is one little problem: you can't just put a comma there... or you shouldn't. The statement is done after *Schriftsteller*. The mehr-part is an additional thought because you already qualified "how" you like unknown authors. You can't answer that question with those 2 informations. If you wanted to, you'd need to connect it using und as you would do with any other 2-item list. But that would sound bad... just as it would in English.

> I like unknown authors predominantly and more than known ones.

So... the more-part is an somewhat isolated after-thought and should be punctuated as such.

> Ich mag überwiegend unbekannte Autoren[; or - ] mehr als bekannte.

A comma is problematic because it is ambiguous. It is not clear that you intend a break there (which you do for the reasons above).
As the sentence is now it is clear, understandable and syntactically correct. However, it still sounds a little weird and at least I would insert some qualification for the second part.

> ... - auf jeden Fall mehr/deutlich mehr/zumindest mehr...

Of course there are other option to phrase the idea but I think there is nothing as succinct as English.

Comment: Super!, also "bekannte" mit klein ist richtig, oder? Wäre, also, *Ich bevorzuge normalerweise unbekannte Schiftssteller bekannten (Schiftstellern) gegenüber* richtig?

Comment: Oh Gott, da bin ich überfragt... :)

Comment: Nee, ich hatte den Kommentar nicht fertig bearbeitet. Jetzt schon. And sorry, my vote limit today is over, so I will +1 vote till tomorrow.

Comment: Bin trotzdem überfragt... aber ich tendiere zu klein, da "Bekannte" eine Eigenbedeutung hat, nämlich "acquaintances"... der Satz könnte also auch so verstanden werden:
" I prefer unknown authors over acquaintances." Das passiert nicht, wenn man's klein hält, aber ich glaube fast, die Regeln wollen groß.

Comment: Ok, interessant, weil wenn der ursprünglicher Satz *ich mag eher blaue Dinge; mehr als rote* wäre, gilt diese Regel  nicht mehr. Ich werde die Frage wiederbearbeiten.

Comment: Sowohl *rote* als auch *bekannte* in den Beispielen sind substantivierte Adjektive und würden daher großgeschrieben, wenn sie alleine stünden wie in folgendem Beispiel: »Ich bevorzuge Literatur, die von Unbekannten verfasst wurde.« Da hier allerdings ein Substantiv (Schriftsteller) auftaucht, auf das sich *bekannte* bezieht, wird es nach § 58 (1) der Rechtschreibregeln kleingeschreiben.

Answer (score 1):

Häufiger üblich als Emanuels und Carstens Satzbau ist die das Substantiv aufschiebende Konstruktion:

```
Ich mag überwiegend unbekannte, mehr als bekannte Schriftsteller.

Ich bevorzuge normalerweise unbekannte gegenüber bekannten Schiftstellern.
```

Comment: Der zweite Satz ist gut aber der erste ist meines Erachtens nach nicht ok und würde weglektoriert. Die Gründe dafür sind dieselben, die in meiner Antwort stehen.

Comment: @Emanuel: Ich weiß nicht ob ich Deinen Einwand überhaupt verstehe. Ein eingeschobenes `auf jeden Fall` wäre m.E. eine Phrase, der nicht viel zuzumessen ist, die aber dem `überwiegend` auf widersprechende Weise gegenübersteht. Entweder überwiegend, oder auf jeden Fall, aber nicht beides. Wenn jmd. aber unbekannte Schriftsteller als Attribut benennt um seine Präferenzen zu verdeutlichen, dann ist damit schon `mehr als bekannte [Schriftsteller]` gesagt. Die seltene Aussnahme könnte in einem Gespräch sein: (...)

Comment: A: "Ich mag v. a. unbekannte, deutsche Schriftsteller." B: "Und was ist mit Kratuscheck, Boislhammer, Wiltlinger und Prütz?" (4 unbekannte, österreichische) "A: Stimmt." und korrigiert sich: "Ich mag überwiegend unbekannte, mehr als bekannte Schriftsteller." Auch nicht zwingend? Ich geb' Dir recht.

Comment: Mir geht's nur um die Zeichensetzung und ich bin der Meinung in dem Satz "Ich mag überwiegend unbekannte mehr als bekannte Schriftsteller" muss entweder ein Semikolon oder ein Bindestrich aber KEIN Komma. Ein Komma ist aus verschiedenen Gründen problematisch. Einen Grund habe ich versucht in meiner Antwort zu erklären. Mir geht's nicht um Wortwahl oder was die beste Übersetzung für predominantly ist... nur um die Interpunktion

Comment: @Emanuel: Ah, das habe ich gar nicht beachtet. War ja auch in einer Klammer versteckt. ;) Zum Glück habe ich nachgefragt.